# Thread with custom states

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is it possible in Java (Android) to implement a customized version of a Thread which carries its own States?

What I mean is:
While ThreadA is in Running state, it still can be polled by ThreadB that asks for its state

```
e.g.
ThreadA.getState();
```

It is possible to modify the states values to some custom ones? So as to implement a sort of basic communication system between those two threads?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply subclass `Thread` and provide your own states therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is possible. I used this a lot in my previous projects, all what you need is to extend the `Thread` class.

```
public class StateThread extends Thread{
   String state = "ThreadState";
   public synchronized void setState(String newState){
      state = newState;
   }
   public synchronized String getState(){
      return state;
   }
   @override
   public void run(){
      // Do stuff and update state...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Java is indeed very powerful

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to perform this task. 
Is it a good design? I don't think so. 
There are other means to perform communication between threads - 
For example, you should use a queue with a Producer/Consumer pattern. 
I am sure that Android, as JavaSE supports thread local - you can use it in order to manage local thread data (including states) (maybe in combination with a queue that will get "operations" to change the state managed by a thread 
If you do decide to go for the solution of having setState and getState methods, at least consider using the ReaderWriterLock to optimize your locking

Comment: +1 for suggesting something that might be worth the hassle. Checking a shared 'state' object directly is not effective because the checked thread does not have to do anything.  I use this approach on embedded jobs - a state object is passed around every thread on its 'normal' input queue or whatever, and must be returned to the low-priority 'LED-blink' thread within 10 seconds. If the object does not come back, the LED stops flashing and the hardware watchdog timer is not refreshed.  This detects stuck or looping threads, (only one core, so a loop elsewhere stops the blink thread running).

Answer (score 1):

Threads *state* is maintained by the Virtual Machine. VM uses the state to monitor and manage the actual thread.

That's why there is no mechanism to modify the *state* of the Thread. There is no `setState` function that allows to set your custom state.

For your application purpose, you can define your own instance variables by extending Thread but that cannot alter Thread's state in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing with shared data is not very useful for determining the 'state' of a thread - the thread writes its state as 'healthy', then gets stuck - the monitor thread then checks the state and finds it healthy.

Monitoring the 'state' should mean making the checked thread do something, not just looking directly at some shared object.

If you have a message-passing design, (as suggested by zaske), you can pass around a 'state record' on the input queue of evey thread, asking it to record its state inside and pass it on to the next thread. The 'monitor' thread waits for the record to come back, all filled in. If it does not get it in a resonable time, it could log what it has got - it keeps a reference to the state record object, so it could see which thread has not updated its state. It could, perhaps, fail to feed a watchdog timer.